# Wait screen with animation error - BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

[image]

Above is my screenshot I am getting while displaying the wait screen using `ActivityIndicatorView`. Any idea why my spinner image is being displayed within a narrow strip?

My code is:

```
ActivityIndicatorView act = new ActivityIndicatorView(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
Bitmap spinImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/spinner.jpg");
act.createActivityImageField(spinImage, 9,Field.FIELD_HCENTER );
LabelField label = new LabelField(message);
DialogFieldManager manager = new DialogFieldManager();
popup = new PopupScreen(manager);
manager.addCustomField(label);
manager.addCustomField(act);
```

**EDIT:** Spinner Image 
[image]

**EDIT 2:** Full spinner image only when No. of frames = 1 and image = spinner.gif
[image]

Comment: add the ActivityIndicatorView  class

Comment: @Signare check this http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/progressindicator/ActivityIndicatorView.html

Comment: please post your multiple-frame spinner image.  we can't debug why you can only get it to work with 1 frame, if you only show the 1 frame image.

Comment: @Nate With multiple frames I get the spinner image within a narrow strip, please see the above image. Moreover, as I said below in a comment  its not animated even when I get the full image(only with 'gif' not 'jpg') with 1 frame and a gif image(see EDIT 2)

Comment: If you want us to help, then upload the multi-frame image.  I'm not sure why this is so difficult.

Comment: @Nate I m not sure what are you asking for? If you want to see how does my spinner image appears when I have multiple frames its the same as my first image(a narrow strip).

Comment: @Nate I m sorry I could not get your question earlier, finally I nailed the problem and it was my image width. Thanks a lot for the suggestion :)

Comment: No problem.  That's why I was asking.  It's easy to have the underlying image be wrong, and the code be correct.  The device was probably trying to divide your single frame image into 1/9ths. Thanks for posting your solution, and accepting it, so we know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Nate and Rupak. 
 I leave this for others facing similar issue. 
 I simply had to use the width of the image frames be the width of a frame multiplied by the total number of frames. Reference [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Indicate_activity_1210002_11.jsp)

I set the number of frames 4 and image: [image]

Answer (score 2):

You didn't upload the ***`img/spinner.jpg`***, so I assumed that the image has only one frame. Try replacing the line

```
act.createActivityImageField(spinImage, 9,Field.FIELD_HCENTER );
```

with the line

```
act.createActivityImageField(spinImage, 1, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
```

Also check the [API documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/progressindicator/ActivityIndicatorView.html#createActivityImageField%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int,%20long%29) carefully.

Comment: The spinner image is a simple jpg image and yes I did try with 1 frame as you mentioned above but it didn't work. You can see my spinner image I added as an edit.

Comment: @Atif Imran, Is the output same when you use `1`?

Comment: Not sure what is going wrong. You can try other values instead of `Field.FIELD_HCENTER` while invoking `createActivityImageField`. Try 0 once.

Comment: I already tried with 0 and 1 with no luck. Changed the style to Bottom, leading etc. Even tried with a 'gif' image and got the full spinner image finally but not animated! Rupak, I need you to solve this!!